# play all audio automatically HTML

Tags: html, audio

I'm trying to play the audio 1 by 1 this code but the only first audio plays.

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="../Audio/kabalyo.wav" type="audio/wav">
  <source src="../Audio/ubing.wav" type="audio/wav">
  <source src="../Audio/lalaki.wav" type="audio/wav">
  <source src="../Audio/babai.wav" type="audio/wav">
  <source src="../Audio/tokininyo.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle :) it's easier for us to just modify your code there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, browsers will pick the first type it can support. It's also important to know that not only having the type attribute on the source element is required, but the file itself should be sent from the server with the proper content-type heading.
To play many songs you must use this code, the only problem is that it only plays MP3's.

First you have to put this code before `<body>`

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var audio;var playlist;var tracks;var current;initaudio();function initaudio(){current=0;audio=$('audio');playlist=$('#playlist');tracks=playlist.find('li a');len=tracks.length-1;audio[0].volume=1;playlist.find('a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();link=$(this);current=link.parent().index();runaudio(link,audio[0])});audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){current++;if(current>len){current=0;link=playlist.find('a')[0]}else{link=playlist.find('a')[current]}runaudio($(link),audio[0])})}function runaudio(link,player){player.src=link.attr('href');par=link.parent();par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');audio[0].load();audio[0].play()}
//]]>
</script>
```

Into the .css

```
#player {
width: 400px;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
#player {
background: url(//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-9dx_GmP6Yeg/U06qBO9M4EI/AAAAAAAAFEY/FXrhlltF7xc/s300/bg.png);
padding: 10px 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
audio {
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
display: inline-block
}
#player:after {
content: url(//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KoD5KVOAsGQ/U1B_dWFttoI/AAAAAAAAFFc/uJ3SjLPlDHQ/s75/equalizador.gif);
padding-left: 10px;
}
#playlist {
margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
display: block;
background: #424242; 
border-top: 5px solid #9F111B;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
text-align: left;
font-size: 12px; 
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
}
#playlist li, #playlist ul li {
background-image: none;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#playlist li a {
color: #CCC; 
background: #222; 
padding: 7px 5px;
display: block;
padding-left: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#playlist li a:hover{
background: #9F111B; 
text-decoration: none;
}
#playlist .active a {
color: #B11623; 
font-style: italic;
text-decoration: none;
}
#playlist .active a:before {
content: "\25B6";
color: #CCC;
font-style: normal;
padding-right: 8px;
}
#playlist .active a:hover {
color: #222;
```

And add this code to the HTML:

```
<div id='player'>
<audio controls='' id='audio' preload='auto' tabindex='0' type='audio/mpeg'>
<source src='URL first song' type='audio/mp3'/>
</audio>
</div>
<ul id='playlist'>
<li class='active'><a href='URL first song'>Name first song</a></li>
<li><a href='URL sencond song'>Name second song</a></li>
<li><a href='URL third song'>Name third song</a></li>
</ul>
```